# Is there any default post_max_size in the jquery-file-upload plugin?

Tags: jquery, symfony, jquery-file-upload, oneupuploaderbundle

Is there any default max size of the file upload that is set in `jquery-file-upload`? I am asking this question since

- I tried [VichUploaderBundle](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle) and was I able to upload 4M-size files
- I found that `post_max_size = 8M` in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

But, each time I use [OneupUploaderBundle](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle) for files like 3 to 4M, I got in the javascript console.

---

**Google Chromium**

```
POST http://localhost/tuto/web/app_dev.php/_uploader/gallery/upload 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

---

**Firefox**

```
POST http://localhost/tuto/web/app_dev.php/_uploader/gallery/upload [HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error 90ms]
```

---

**app/logs/dev.log**

```
\ExceptionListener::onKernelException". [] []
[2014-10-21 21:24:53] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileException: "The file "another_ubuntu_wallpaper__raring_ringtail__by_360_graphics-d60693r.jpg" exceeds your upload_max_filesize ini directive (limit is 2048 kb)." at /home/amine/NetBeansProjects/tuto/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.php line 251 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\File\\Exception\\FileException: The file \"another_ubuntu_wallpaper__raring_ringtail__by_360_graphics-d60693r.jpg\" exceeds your upload_max_filesize ini directive (limit is 2048 kb). at /home/amine/NetBeansProjects/tuto/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.php:251)"} []
```

Below is my code:

```
    $(function () {
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            dataType: 'json',
            done: function (e, data) {
                $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                    $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Thank you for telling me how to set this max to 8M for example.

---

By the way, please add the tag `OneupUploaderBundle` to stackoverflow.com.

Comment: check apache and php logs. they might tell you something

Comment: I am quite sure that the problem is not due to apache. In fact, I was able to upload files like 4M of size by using the `VichUploaderBundle`. I am quite sure that the problem comes from `jquery-file-upload`.

Comment: did you try in a different browser?

Comment: I will try with a different browser when I am back home!

Comment: You can inspect the return value of the request with the dev tools in your browser. This way you're able to see the error message of the exception that causes this 500. Could you provide this information?

Comment: @devsheeep I will do that when I am back home... Thanks!

Comment: @devsheeep I do still have the same error with firefox. Notice that firefox give me that the operation took 90ms. See my question I have edited now!

Comment: @devsheeep do you think that there is a timeout in the plugin?

Comment: Possible. Yet still: Can you inspect the ajax request through the Inspector (Chrome) or FireBug (Firefox) and provide the content of the "Response"-Tab? It will tell you exactly why the request failed. Or check the `app/log/dev.log` or server error log for more information.

Comment: I found an error in `app/logs/dev.log`. I edited my question to see the error! Should I make another question to make it easily understandable for others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finaly found the solution.

I have set also that param `upload_max_filesize = 8M`  in addition to `post_max_size = 8M` in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

Thank you @devsheeep for being helpful.